# A shape I draw doesn't remain in its intended place

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell, shapes

VBA macro for Word. I have a 15 X 3 table. In cell(3,3) I merge 9 rows. In the merged cell I have to write "Text 1", move to a para below and draw a rectangle (height 10, width 100, color). Super impose on it another rectange, same x, y location, same height, but 25% width and white color. This I do 3 times one below the other. The issue I face is the color rectangle jumps to cell(3,1) and the white remains in cell(3,3) but it also vanishes when I put it in a loop. I would like to group the rectangles and anchor them to the place in the merged cell (3,3).
I would greatly appreciate any help

```vb
Sub DrawSkillLevelCharts(StartRow, StartColumn, paraNo, I)
    Dim leftPos As Single
    Dim topPos As Single
    Dim chartWidth As Single
    Dim barHeight As Single
    Dim superWidth As Single
    Dim startCell As cell
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim mainBarChart As Shape
    Dim superimposedBar As Shape
    barHeight = 10
    Set currentRange = myTable.cell(StartRow, StartColumn).Range.Paragraphs(paraNo).Range

    With currentRange
        .Collapse 0
        .Move Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        .Select
    End With
    leftPos = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
    topPos = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    chartWidth = 100
    superWidth = chartWidth * (I * 0.25)
            
    ' Draw main bar chart and anchor it to the cell
    Set mainBarChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftPos, topPos, _ 
            chartWidth, barHeight, currentRange)
    mainBarChart.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 86, 35)
    mainBarChart.Anchor = currentRange
    ' Draw superimposed white bar and anchor it to the cell
    Set superimposedBar = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftPos, topPos, _
            superWidth, barHeight, currentRange)
    superimposedBar.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    superimposedBar.Anchor = currentRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting shapes into Word tables with VBA is more complex compared to Excel. Some parameter tuning is required to position the shapes correctly.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub DrawSkillLevelCharts()
    Dim leftPos As Single
    Dim topPos As Single
    Dim chartWidth As Single
    Dim barHeight As Single
    Dim superWidth As Single
    Dim startCell As Cell
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim mainBarChart As Shape
    Dim superimposedBar As Shape
    Dim cellFirst, cellDest, myTable, j, sTxt
    ' ****************
    Dim StartRow, StartColumn, paraNo, I
    ' Parameters from caller
    StartRow = 3:    StartColumn = 3
    paraNo = 2:     I = 1
    barHeight = 13
    ' ****************
    Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set cellFirst = myTable.Cell(1, 1).Range
    Set cellDest = myTable.Cell(StartRow, StartColumn)
    sTxt = "Text1"
    For j = 1 To paraNo
        sTxt = sTxt & vbCr
    Next j
    With cellDest.Range
        ' Update content in the merged cell
        .Text = sTxt
        .Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
        ' Move to target paragraph
        .Move Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=paraNo - 1
        .Select
    End With
    'LeftPadding is used to adjust the Left pos
    leftPos = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) - cellDest.LeftPadding
    topPos = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    chartWidth = 100
    superWidth = chartWidth * (I * 0.25)
    ' Draw main bar chart and anchor it to the cell
    Set mainBarChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        leftPos, topPos, chartWidth, barHeight, cellFirst)
    mainBarChart.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 86, 35)
    ' Draw superimposed white bar and anchor it to the cell
    Set superimposedBar = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        leftPos, topPos, superWidth, barHeight, cellFirst)
    superimposedBar.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your efforts to work on my code. It works

Comment: Accept it as answer will be helpful for other OP users.